# Where does the second term in this harmonic motion come from?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

> **Question:** 
>   $$
> \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + \omega^2 x = 2\sin \Omega t .
> $$
>   Determine the motion of the object, given that $x (0)= -4$ and $x'(0)=0$.
>
> **Answer:** 
>   $$
> x (t) = -4\cos\omega t - \frac {\Omega}{\omega}\frac{2}{\omega^2-\Omega^2}\sin \omega t + \frac{2}{\omega^2-\Omega^2}\sin \Omega t .
> $$

**My Attempt:**

I was able to find that homogeneous equation is

$h=-4\cos(\omega t)$

and a particular solution is given by

$p=\dfrac{2\sin(\Omega t)}{\omega^2-\Omega^2} $

**Working for $p$:**

$p$ is in the form:

$p=a\cos(\Omega t)+b\sin(\Omega t)$

$p' = -a\Omega \sin(\Omega t) +b\Omega \cos(\Omega t)$

$p'' = -\Omega^2 p$

Substituting into our original second-order ODE, we get

$p=\dfrac{2\sin(\Omega t)}{\omega^2-\Omega^2} $

**My solution**

Now,

$x(t) = h+p$

Therefore,

$x(t) =-4\cos(\omega t) +\dfrac{2\sin(\Omega t)}{\omega^2-\Omega^2} $

But as you can see, the **Answer** at the top of this post is different (there is a middle term). I think I've missed something fundamental. Help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where do you take into account the initial conditions ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust To determine the homogenous solution h(t)=Acosωt+Bsinωt. I solved that initially then got A = -4, B = 0. Then I found the particular solution.

Comment: Because of the particular solution, your solution does not verify the initial conditions.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Oh, I see. Because I did a similar question earlier where d^2(x)/dy^(2) +w^2*x = 0, and there was no particular solution for that, just the homogenous one, since the ODE = 0. In that case the answer was just x(t) = -4cos(wt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homogeneous solutions are
$$
h (t) = a\cos \omega t + b\sin \omega t ,
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are reals. The proposed particular solution is correct:
$$
p (t) = \frac{2}{\omega^2 - \Omega^2} \sin \Omega t .
$$
Now, form $x = h+p$ and apply the initial conditions to determine $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hi Harry! But I determined for the homogeneous solution, based on the initial conditions, a = -4 and b =0, therefore h(t) = -4cos(wt)

Comment: so basically I need to apply initial conditions after doing x = h+p? Because I did a similar question earlier where d^2(x)/dy^(2) +w^2*x = 0, and there was no particular solution for that, just the homogenous one. In that case the answer was just x(t) = -4cos(wt)

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll keep that in mind when solving initial value problems.

Answer (score 2):

The general solution of the homogeneous ODE is :
$$x(t)=c_1\sin(\omega t)+c_2\cos(\omega t)$$
Don't take the boundary conditions into account at this stage : this would be a mistake because the conditions are for the non-homogeneous ODE, not for the homogeneous. That is not the same !

The general solution of the non-homogeneous ODE is :
$$x(t)=c_1\sin(\omega t)+c_2\cos(\omega t)+\frac{2\sin(\Omega t)}{\omega^2-\Omega^2}$$
Now you can take the conditions into account in order to find $c_1$ and $c_2$. I suppose that you can take it from here.